# Copying values from excel to body of outlook email vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, com, outlook

So this is a more refined version of a question I asked earlier. I have been trying to sort this out for quite a while. I found a site that makes sense, but I can't implement it for some reason. I just want to be able to copy information from excel (tables, charts, ranges, etc) into the body of an outlook email.

From here:
http://pastebin.com/4VWmcrx6

It suggests:

```
Using VB.NET to copy Excel Range (a table) to body of Outlook email
Sub CopyFromExcelIntoEMail()
Dim Doc As Word.Document
Dim wdRn As Word.Range
Dim Xl As Excel.Application
Dim Ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim xlRn As Excel.Range

Set Doc = Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor
Set wdRn = Doc.Range

Set Xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
Set Ws = Xl.Workbooks("Mappe1.xls").Worksheets(1)

Set xlRn = Ws.Range("b2", "c6")
xlRn.Copy

wdRn.Paste
End Sub
```

I have tried several variations of it, but with no luck.

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports Office = Microsoft.Office.Core
Imports xlNS = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports excel1 = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports word1 = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
Imports outlook1 = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim Doc As Word.Document
        Dim wdRn As Word.Range
        Dim Xl As Excel.Application
        Dim Ws As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim xlRn As Excel.Range

        Dim application As New Outlook.Application
        Dim mail As Outlook.MailItem = CType(application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem), Outlook.MailItem)


        Doc = Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor
        wdRn = Doc.Range

        Xl = GetObject("C:\Users\ajohnson\Desktop\Book1.xlsx", "Excel.Application")
        Ws = Xl.Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets(1)

        xlRn = Ws.Range("a1", "d2")
        xlRn.Copy()

        With mail
            .Body = wdRn.Paste() & vbCr & wdRn.Paste()

        End With

    End Sub

End Module
```

It doesn't seem like it should be that difficult and I have a reasonable idea of what is going on, but no matter what I try it does not work. That code throws a com exception on

```
Doc = Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor
```

I also tried using the code as it was give, but it says application is undefined.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thank you as always.

For posterity (I see this question all over the place): The solution from @Siddharth Rout will definitely work, but if you are trying to make it not get truncated on blackberries (it actually comes up, I swear) a better approach can be found in the comments.

```
Sub Export_Range_Images()

' =========================================
' Code to save selected Excel Range as Image
' =========================================

Dim oRange As Range
Dim oCht As Chart
Dim oImg As Picture
Set oRange = Range("A1:B2")
Set oCht = Charts.Add
oRange.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
oCht.Paste

oCht.Export FileName:="C:\temp\SavedRange.jpg", Filtername:="JPG"

End Sub
```

This comes from [here](http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2010/06/how-to-save-excel-range-as-image-using.html), along with:

```
.HTMLBody="< img src='C:\Temp\logo.jpg'>" & vbCr & "< img src='C:\Temp\logo.jpg'>"
```

From [here.](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=529993)

The idea being that you create .jpg files of the ranges/tables you are interested in and then use html to put them in the body of the email. Between these two approaches you should be able to get it working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used Ron's `RangetoHTML` function here.

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports Olook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook

Public Class Form1
    '~~> Define your Excel Objects
    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xlRange As Excel.Range

    '~~> Define Outlook Objects
    Dim olApp As New Olook.Application
    Dim olMail As Olook.MailItem

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        '~~> Opens an exisiting Workbook. Change path and filename as applicable
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Sample.xlsx")
        '~~> Set the relevant sheet that we want to work with
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")

        xlRange = xlWorkSheet.Range("A1:F20")

        olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)

        On Error Resume Next
        With olMail
            .To = "INSERT TO EMAIL HERE"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
            .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(xlRange)
            .Display()   'or use .Send to send it
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0

        '~~> Close the File
        xlWorkBook.Close (False)

        '~~> Quit the Excel Application
        xlApp.Quit()

        '~~> Clean Up
        releaseObject (xlApp)
        releaseObject (xlWorkBook)

        '~~> Similarly cleanup for outlook. not including as I am using .Display()

    End Sub

    Function RangetoHTML(rng As Excel.Range)
        ' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
        ' Working in Office 2000-2010
        Dim fso As Object
        Dim ts As Object
        Dim TempFile As String
        Dim TempWB As Excel.Workbook

        TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

        'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
        rng.Copy()

        TempWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(1)

        With TempWB.Sheets(1)
            .Cells(1).PasteSpecial(Paste:=8)
            .Cells(1).PasteSpecial(-4163, , False, False)
            .Cells(1).PasteSpecial(-4122, , False, False)
            .Cells(1).Select()
            xlApp.CutCopyMode = False
            On Error Resume Next
            .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
            .DrawingObjects.Delete()
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With

        'Publish the sheet to a htm file
        With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
             SourceType:=4, _
             Filename:=TempFile, _
             Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
             Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
             HtmlType:=0)
            .Publish (True)
        End With

        'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
        fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
        RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
        ts.Close()
        RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                              "align=left x:publishsource=")

        'Close TempWB
        TempWB.Close(savechanges:=False)

        'Delete the htm file we used in this function
        Kill (TempFile)

        ts = Nothing
        fso = Nothing
        TempWB = Nothing
    End Function

    '~~> Release the objects
    Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
        Try
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject (obj)
            obj = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            obj = Nothing
        Finally
            GC.Collect()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: A great suggestion. The one thing I am running into is that it is difficult to read on blackberry, which of course is the nightmare I am living in. What we do currently is paste things as pictures. Do you think there is a way to do that? From my reading it seems like I might be able to save a range as a .jpg and then include the image in the file (html style with <img src>). Thanks again for the good idea to try.

Comment: Change your BB model. Use blackberry torch 9860 like I do LOL. Ok Joke apart, yes you can insert images as well. Give it a try and if you get stuck, lemme know and I will give you an example :)

Comment: Oh man, you have no idea how bad I want to just say, "blackberries suck, just use anything else," but of course that would not go over well. The problem I run into with pictures is that I don't have access to the clipboard. I know how to select my range in excel and copy as an image, but I can't dump it into the body of an email. Should I be using RangetoHTML for that as well somehow? Perhaps some modification to it? You are my hero if you have a way of getting that to work! :D I will tinker and let you know if I get a solution.

Comment: Yes, i have a solution but I will wait till you give it a try? There is no bigger joy than discovering a solution yourself ;)

Comment: Right on, well so far it seems like the solution that seemed obvious to me (changing .copy to .copypicture as per what is done in the macro recorder) is no good: rng.CopyPicture(Excel.XlPictureAppearance.xlScreen, Excel.XlCopyPictureFormat.xlPicture)

Comment: `What we do currently is paste things as pictures.` Quick question out of curiosity. Why do you want to insert excel range as an image? Because everyone is doing the same?

Comment: I want to insert excel ranges as an image, so I can get tables from an excel worksheet into the body of an outlook email (very similar to what RangetoHTML does), but still have it be readable on blackberries. I have tested it and found that if I do a RangetoHTML approach and have tables like your solution suggests the list gets truncated quickly on a blackberry (they suck, I know), but if I copy the tables as images and paste them in the body of the email, then everyone can read them on their blackberries.

Comment: Ah ok. :) Got it. Give it a try. In the mean time I will write the code for it. Will paste it the moment you confirm that you are not able to do it :) Fair enough?

Comment: Sounds fair to me. Am I right to think I need to modify the RangetoHTML function somehow? I feel like changing paste special would do it, but I have tried changing it to copy as picture and then paste it as picture, but it is not playing nice. I did find another work around: saving ranges as jpg files and then loading them into the body with <img src>, but I am curious about this approach, because it seems much cleaner (no creating a bunch of jpgs).

Comment: Do you know how to export excel range as an image? If yes then you can simply use this code `olMail.Attachments.Add "C:\MyImage.jpg"` and then finally `olMail.HTMLBody = "<html><p>This is a picture.</p>" & "<img src='cid:MyImage.jpg' height=480 width=360>"`

Comment: Yep, I was using:http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2010/06/how-to-save-excel-range-as-image-using.html and http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=529993 to do that approach. Should I just stick with that? I have been trying to modify the RangetoHTML function to get it to do pictures and I have been having no luck. Did you get it to work? The <img src> approach seems to work fine, but if RangetoHTML does it, I would be interested in seeing it. Thank you for you help!

Comment: So you went hunting ;) Well I would suggest the way as I mentioned in my last comment as it is simple. If you follow the `RangetoHTML` way then you will have to create a temp file with image inserted into it and then read the code behind it which is possible but little messy in my opinion.

Comment: I am happy to create some .jpgs and <img src> my way to success. Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Siddharth, nice answer.  I just noticed that you use `TempFile = Environ$("temp")...`  I've always just dumped mine in the directory of the addin or whatever, and then (hopefully) Killed them.  Your way seems much better.  Is Environ$("temp") reliably available in various Windows versions?